# Recycler view reach on top after add some data on scroll in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have added notifyDataSetChange still it reach at top of recycler view if anybody see any mistake in code please reply. I am loading data on scrolling form server bt set it in adapter on bottom reach, here VegList is a list which contain old data with newly added data.

I have already seen all related endless recycler view so no need such type of suggestions, not fresher.

Comment: One of the most important uses of recycleview is that we can refresh the view individually.By calling  notifyDataSetChanged  you are refreshing the entire view .. Use vegAdaper.notifyItemInserted(temp.size() -1); instead of   notifyDataSetChanged. Also you are creating a new adapter each time ie is pretty bad ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this issue because you are creating a new adapter each time loadmore is called.

You need to rewrite the code like this.

initialize adapter in 
**onCreate** like this

```
vegAdaper = new VegAdapter(this,vegList); 
recycleView.setAdapter(vegAdapter);
```

Please remove all the code from temp arraylist creation to vegAdaper.notifyDatasetChanged()

and change it to this single line

```
  vegAdaper.notifyItemInserted(vegList.size() -1);    // this will notify the new items in vegList.. Not the entire view.
```

Also please post the actual code instead of image.

Comment: I can't use VegList in vegAdapter because I am passing ArrayList parameter in adpater's constructor and VegList is a List type variable

Comment: And I have used to notifyItemInserted as you define still no success

Comment: In that case you can easily change vegList to an arralist right,,? What did you passed instead of vegList.. ?

Comment: Thanks dude your are right I removed code of creating new adapter each time and problem is solved even still I use notifyDataSetChange().

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position before you call notifyDataSetChanged().And after that you can called the setSelection(position); to get the listview or whatever back to the original place.

Comment: It's a recycler view not a grid view